# Error message: Host 'server1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, email, localhost, hostname, hosts

I have a web and mail server running Ubuntu 12.04. I installed iRedMail and had it running fine, but this morning mail was not connecting and none of my sites worked. I checked some logs which told me to run mysqladmin flush-hosts. That may have put the sites online, but they went up and down and I'm not sure it did anything.

`Mar 28 15:13:19 server1 roundcube: MDB2 Error: unknown error (-1): _doConnect: [Error message: Host 'server1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server] [Native code: 1130] [Native message: Host 'server1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server]`

Then I found this and wondered why it didn't say localhost. Shouldn't localhost be trying to connect to mysql?

Here's `/etc/hostname/`

`server1`

Here's `/etc/hosts`

```
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters


127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# Auto-generated hostname. Please do not remove this comment.
MY.IP.222.333 server1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD  server1
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

My hunch is that there is something wrong with these files, as requests should be coming from `localhost`.

EDIT: I've looked around in config files for something not pointing to 127.0.0.1 or localhost, but no joy, they all do.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with iRedMail installed and ClamD removed using [this tutorial](http://techintherain.blogspot.ca/2013/03/how-to-disable-clamav-from-iredmail-or.html)

Edit: [This pptp script](http://www.putdispenserhere.com/pptp-debian-ubuntu-openvz-setup-script/) was the problem. Particularly,

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to $ip
# saves iptables routing rules and enables them on-boot
iptables-save &gt; /etc/iptables.conf
```

Where `$ip` is my server's public IP. After I enable that, I can VPN tunnel through the server, but all web traffic seems to lead back to itself? I would appreciate if someone knows another way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your webserver is connecting to your public IP to get to mysql. Check your application config to make sure the database server is 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Comment: Ok, but it's happening with all services, websites, webmail, Mail.app. I will check each.

Comment: Here's from /etc/dovecot-mysql.conf :

`connect = host=127.0.0.1` , Yet `/var/log/dovecot.log` says `Mar 28 17:42:45 auth-worker: Error: mysql(127.0.0.1): Connect failed to database (vmail): Host 'server1.MY_DOMAIN.TLD' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server - waiting for 125 seconds before retry`

Comment: /etc/amavis/conf.d/ says 
`@storage_sql_dsn = (
    ['DBI:mysql:database=amavisd;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306', 'amavisd', 'HASHEDPASSWORD?'],
);`

Comment: Can you think of other places to look?

Comment: The error message was from roundcoube, its config is still missing. By the way: please add additional information to your question, not to comments on an answer. Especially because my answer is looking a bit bogus by now and I may delete at so it doesn't distract.

Answer (score 0):

[This pptp script](http://www.putdispenserhere.com/pptp-debian-ubuntu-openvz-setup-script/) was the problem. Particularly,

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to $ip
# saves iptables routing rules and enables them on-boot
iptables-save &gt; /etc/iptables.conf
```

Where `$ip` is my server's public IP. After I enable that, I can VPN tunnel through the server, but all web traffic seems to lead back to itself? I would appreciate if someone knows another way.

I found out by reinstalling 12.04, reinstalling iRedMail, putting my sites back, up, then doing the PPTP steps. I used the VPN for a while and realized everything else was down. Flushing the NAT tables fixed it.

Comment: The problem seems to be exclusive to ServerCrate OpenVZ VPS. I'm talking with them about a solution. I will comment again with how I feel about their responsiveness later.